# Mudar a cor do Label de um grafico no PrimeFaces

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um gráfico e as `labels` que ficam no eixo x estão com uma cor muito escura e eu gostaria de trocar essa cor, já tentei mudar a propriedade color do gráfico porém só o titulo muda.

```
<p:chart  type="bar" model="#{graficoBarraBean.barModel}" style="height:300px;color:green" />
```

O gráfico fica dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que mal da pra enxergar os nomes embaixo do gráfico.

---

**UPDATE:**
Veja que tento mudar a cor pelo modo desenvolvedor do navegador e mesmo assim não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você pode colar o HTML gerado em um fiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Alterando a cor das labels**

Precisamos acessar as opções do [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) via javaScript, adicione na sua página ou no javaScript da tela:

**Nota:** Atera o eixo X e eixo Y

```
function alterarTextoLabel() { 
  this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = { 
   textColor : 'sua cor desejada' 
 }; 
this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions = { 
   textColor : 'sua cor desejada' 
 }; 
}
```

**1# opção** no bean do seu Chart adicione:

```
barModel.setExtender("alterarTextoLabel");
```

**2# opção** Você pode também adicionar o `extender` como um atributo do P:chart

```
 <p:chart extender="alterarTextoLabel">
```

**Nota 2 :** O atributo `extender` foi alterado na versão 5.0 do [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf), assim a segunda opção só está disponível nas inferiores.

***Bônus:*** **Alterando a cor do background no chart**

```
.jqplot-base-canvas { 
background:"cor desejada"; 
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Estamos aqui pra isso, @Techies, pra quem deu downvote poderia explicar o motivo?

Comment: Acho que foi porque você não tinha completado a resposta ainda.

Comment: Acho que foi isso mesmo :(

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que sobrescrever o css, tente isso:

```
.jqplot-series-canvas {
  background:green;
}
```

**Edição:**

Então tente o seguinte:

```
.jqplot-title{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.jqplot-xaxis-label{
    color: #FF0000; 
}
.jqplot-yaxis-label{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou. :/

Comment: Só a cor do titulo mudou pra vermelha, os label's continuam da mesma cor

Comment: @Techies dá uma olhada nessa parte aqui da [documentação](https://speakerdeck.com/player/057b8d7962d2466f9f24cd45f559b8da?slide=91#) sobre onde e aplicar o css pra mudar a cores e outras coisas. Acredito que a última pode te servir.

Comment: Ja olhei, eu tento usar e a cor não muda mesmo assim rsrs

Comment: tentou colocar !important ?

Comment: ainda não, vou tentar

Comment: Também não deu ..

Comment: Coloquei no CSS do template, e só o titulo muda de cor rs

Comment: Acabei de tentar fazer isso, editei a pergunta com uma imagem, de uma olhada.

Comment: Já tentei limpar o cash, eu tirei o trecho css que estava no arquivo sistema.css e tentei alterar a cor pelo navegador. Só a cor do titulo muda, os resto não.